# Installing ROS in centOS

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Is there any way I can install ROS in centOS? I get this error even if I try to install minimum packages.

[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Could not detect OS, tried ['rosdep_test_os', 'debian', 'ubuntu', 'ubuntu', 'opensuse', 'fedora', 'rhel', 'arch', 'osx', 'osxbrew', 'gentoo', 'cygwin', 'freebsd']

I know ROS is not yet ready for centOS, but did anyone tried, any tricks to make it work?

Thanks in advance,
dksr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30994/installing-ros-in-centos/) by [Krishna Dubba](https://answers.ros.org/users/2103/krishna-dubba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be able to use the [ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE) environment variable and tell rosdep that you're running rhel.  RHEL is not heavily used either so you may need to generate new rules for system dependencies for that as well.

There are some tutorials on updating rules on the [rosdep wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrwilliams](https://answers.ros.org/users/12531/jrwilliams/) on 2014-02-27**:
I'm trying to install ROS on CentOS as well. I've tried setting ROS_OS_OVERRIDE to rhel, but for many many packages I get a "No definition of [PACKAGENAME] for os [rhel]". I'm totally new to ROS and am required to use CentOS for this. Can you point me in the right direction to resolving this issue?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-02-27**:
You will need to contribute rosdep rules for the package for CentOS http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html has instructions on how to do so.